# Should "The history of X" be followed by "began" or "begins"?

Tags: tenses

[This BBC page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/history_of_the_earth) states

> The history of life on Earth **began** about 3.8 billion years ago...

Similarly, [this one](http://www.bbc.co.uk/religion/0/21834319) states

> The history of Canterbury's religious significance **began** with the Romans...

However, [this page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/religion/religions/rastafari/history/history.shtml) states

> The history of Rastafari **begins** with the colonisation of Africa...

as does [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/documentaries/2010/09/100917_documentary_marching_into_history.shtml):

> The history of the march **begins** in the village of Tolpuddle...

Which is correct/preferred, or are both equally acceptable?

Comment: The use of the present tense in this way is idiomatic and a well accepted structure. One might be more inclined to the idiomatic form in a conversational setting, perhaps if one were retelling a story, as opposed to giving some bald fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a stylistic choice, called the [narrative time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrative_mode#Narrative_time). In the first two examples, the **narrative past** is used; it is by far the most common narrative style of recounting history or stories (*once upon a time, there lived...*).

In the second, the **narrative present** (also called the historical present) is used. It is as an attempt to draw the viewer/reader into that particular story's time-frame as if they are there to witness it as it is happening. Interestingly this is more common is spontaneous speech (recounting of facts or story) than in writing (...and *then* he **says** to her, ...).

The choice is yours.

Comment: Google n-gram shows an equal mix in the 20th century: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=history+of+*+begins%2Chistory+of+*+began&year_start=1900 but a preference for "begins" in the 21st: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=history+of+*+begins%2Chistory+of+*+began&year_start=1900 , perhaps influenced by a small number of works which are often quoted.